# Hibernate 4 takes more than 1 minute to persist 80MB blob

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

we have recently migrated to JBoss **7.1.1** from JBoss **6** and therefore switched from hibernate **3.6.6** to hibernate **4.0.1** and encountered an issue when storing blob data to the database.
Persisting a blob of ~80MB took less than 10s with hibernate 3, but with hibernate 4 it takes more than 1 minute to persist it. I have tried several versions of hibernate 4 - 4.0.x,4.1.x,4.2.x and the behaviour is the same.

Environment:

jboss 7.1.1, hibernate 4.0.1, ojdbc6, Oracle DB 11.2.0.3.0 - **> 1 min**
jboss 6.1.0, hibernate 3.6.6, ojdbc6, Oracle DB 11.2.0.3.0 - **~ 10 sec**

I also turned on logging to TRACE level to see where the time is being consumed and found the following:

```
17:33:58,203 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue] Adding an EntityInsertAction for [x.x.datastore.persistence.LobDataOutEntity] object
17:33:58,204 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue] Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityInsertAction[x.x.datastore.persistence.LobDataOutEntity#2972533]]
17:33:58,205 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue] Adding resolved non-early insert action.
17:33:58,206 TRACE [org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions] No unresolved entity inserts that depended on [[x.x.datastore.persistence.LobDataOutEntity#2972533]]
**17:33:58,206 TRACE [org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions] No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
17:34:21,162 TRACE [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener]  Flushing session**
17:34:21,163 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener]  Processing flush-time cascades
17:34:21,163 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade] Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: x.x.datastore.persistence.LobDataOutEntity
17:34:21,164 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade] Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: x.x.datastore.persistence.LobDataOutEntity
17:34:21,189 TRACE [org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister] Dehydrating entity: [x.x.datastore.persistence.LobDataOutEntity#2972533]
17:34:21,189 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 2972533
17:34:21,190 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] binding parameter [2] as [BLOB] - oracle.sql.BLOB@67c6db48
17:34:48,845 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] binding parameter [3] as [CLOB] - <null>
**17:34:48,846 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch] Executing batch size: 1
17:35:21,295 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations] Success of batch update unknown: 0**
17:35:21,295 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl] Releasing statement [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6@52cc5b6]
17:35:21,296 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl] Closing prepared statement [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6@52cc5b6]
17:35:21,297 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl] Starting after statement execution processing [AFTER_STATEMENT]
17:35:21,297 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl] Skipping aggressive release due to manual disabling
17:35:21,298 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl] Starting after statement execution processing [AFTER_STATEMENT]
17:35:21,299 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] Releasing JDBC connection
17:35:21,299 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] Released JDBC connection
17:35:21,300 TRACE [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener] Post flush
```

From the above tracing logs the time seems to add up when the parameters are being bound to the query and somewhere in the flushing part of the execution. What has changed in hibernate 4 that would cause such delay?

Is there anyone that can give me more insights? Thanks a lot for you help :)

I've added my configuration and source code below.

**#persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="DAL-connector-persistence">
  <description>Persistence unit for SyncML module</description>
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DS</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.CustomOracleDialect"/> //the custom dialect is built over Oracle10gDialect
      <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="true"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="30"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="30"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true">  </property>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**#DS definition**

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/****DS" pool-name="***LDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
   <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@@oracle.ds.ip@:@oracle.ds.sid@</xa-datasource-property>
   <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
   <driver>oracle</driver>
   <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
   <xa-pool>
       <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
       <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
       <prefill>true</prefill>
       <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
   </xa-pool>
   <security>
       <security-domain>***DS-oracle-encrypted-password</security-domain>
   </security>
   <recovery no-recovery="true"/>
   <validation>
       <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
       <background-validation>true</background-validation>
       <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
   </validation>
   <timeout>
       <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
       <idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes>
   </timeout>
   <statement>
       <track-statements>true</track-statements>
       <prepared-statement-cache-size>1000</prepared-statement-cache-size>
   </statement>
</xa-datasource>
```

**#Java code**

```
//lob initialization
LobDataOutEntity lobEntity = new LobDataOutEntity(); 
Session session = (Session) manager.getDelegate(); 
Blob newContent = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(new byte[]{}); 
lobEntity.setBlobData(newContent); 
manager.persist(lobEntity);


//read chunks of bytes and write them into the blob
while (...)
{
  lobEntity.getBlobData().setBytes(wrote + 1, b64DataBuf);
}

//merge the content when all bytes have been written into the blob
manager.merge(lobEntity);
```

Comment: I see a big difference between `17:34:21,190 TRACE` and `17:34:48,845 TRACE`. Are you sure you have the same configuration for the datasource as before? I would try: 1. Check this [problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253323/how-to-persist-large-blobs-100mb-in-oracle-using-hibernate) 2. Debug in Hibernate a bit to see the exact problem (hibernate is open source, simply attach the source code of the correct hibernate version).

Comment: Its also a bit premature to point the finger at Hibernate; your application server also radically changed. Jboss 7.1.1 has quite a lot of of bugs in it, you might want to try building a 7.2 version from source (you can use these steps: http://blog.kaltepoth.de/posts/2013/02/12/building-jboss-as7.html, but instead of 7.1.3 you get the 7.2 tag) and see if that improves anything.

Comment: Thanks four your quick reply. Upon your suggestion I have downloaded jboss-eap-6.2 and deployed my app there. The result is the same. Still  over 1 minute and the waits in the hibernate logs are exactly the same. Just to exclude the applicaton server I will downgrade hibernate to the version I know it's working in Jboss 7.1 and see how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Update Hibernate, many significant improvements related to Blob storage (and much more) were applied since version 4.0.x.
Take version 4.2.15.Final or - if you're ready for JPA 2.1 - version 4.3.6.Final, these are the most stable and efficient versions at time of writing this.

I expect these recent versions to outperform the older 3.6.x line as well, if I'm wrong please let us know some more details on the [project JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH).

Also, why on earth should you upgrade to JBoss 7.1 today? It's outdated and unmaintained. You can now [download the latest Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap/download/) - for free for development purposes, which is based on JBoss 7.+ but including thousands of bugfixes and improvements, or [get the latest version of WildFly](http://www.wildfly.org), a bit more bleeding edge but containing all the same improvements and fixes too.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! 
I have tried the 4.2.15.Final version with JBoss 7.1 and the result is the same. Still over 1 minute.
I got the same timing(>1 min) when testing with hibernate 4.2.6 version that ships with JBoss-eap-6.2.
I have edited my initial post and added details on my persistence.xml file, DS configuration and java code that creates the BLOB.
Do you see anything flagrantly wrong with them?
 
 To answer your question, we are using JBoss 7.1 as an intermediary version for upgrading JBoss from 6.1.0 AS.

Comment: I have also run my test on JBoss eap 6.2 with Hiberntae 4.2.15.Final and the result is the same. I have opened a bug in JIRA where I've added more details on the configuration I've used.[JIRA ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9319)