# java heap memory Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

In my application I have a heap memory exception : I increase the heap memory with JVM argument but it doesn't solve the problem :
Here is the exception :

```
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.hibernate.type.ByteArrayBlobType.deepCopy(ByteArrayBlobType.java:76)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.deepCopy(TypeFactory.java:374)
at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:184)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:854)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:729)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1994)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BatchingCollectionInitializer.initialize(BatchingCollectionInitializer.java:52)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:63)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1716)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:454)
at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:844)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:241)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1860)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:48)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.BatchingEntityLoader.load(BatchingEntityLoader.java:82)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3049)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:399)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:375)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:815)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:808)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$1.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:519)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:512)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:506)
 `
```

Please Help thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe some malicious entity mapping (causing circular references)

Comment: Can you paste the code of the Session initialization and query execution?

Comment: Check this other question with the same problem as you. Maybe is the same cause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234995/hibernate-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Comment: You seem to be loading entities containing blobs, and these blobs probably contain large amounts of bytes.

Comment: Yes I have entities containing blobs which are loaded on server startup, the server start well but when I try to list or modify these entities sometimes I have this error and the application steal work any help please thanks

Comment: I see it is a deep copy, which means you will have two big entities. Maybe you can just keep one or do modification on the original one.

Comment: Hibernate can use up your memory by handling blobs, here is a fix: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2452481#p2452481

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to persist LARGE BLOBs (>100MB) in Oracle using Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253323/how-to-persist-large-blobs-100mb-in-oracle-using-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are getting the instance of SessionFactory through some singleton mechanism.  I had this problem when I started learning hibernate.  You can check jvm performance using **jconsole**.  Type jconsole in command prompt and check the performance variation and optimise the code